selecting a random cell based on the probability assigned to that cell
I need to pick a random cell from data of names placed in horizontal manner instead of vertical and the probability of picking a random cell is specified in the cell next to each name cell. If cell A2 has a name then cell B2 has its probability then cell C2 has a name and cell D2 has its probability and so on.
*note-i can not use rows below or above the given data and no extra rows can be inserted. I can only use the columns available after the data.
sample file attached.
I searched for the solution and found something but it was for the data placed in vertical manner.

I believe you just need to generate a random number X between 0 and 1 using RAND().
If this X is less than 0.5, your final pick would be "Joe"; if X is between 0.5 and 0.65, you final pick would be "Rima";
if X is between 0.65 and 0.85, your final pick would be "Kylie";
if X is between 0.85 and 0.9, final pick is "Varun";
and if X is between 0.9 and 1.0, final pick is "John".
So all you need to do is to reshape your Probs + Names table using WRAPROWS and then leverage the "Exact match or next larger item" search option of XLOOKUP to map "Prob" to "Name".
The formula would be:
=LET(
    data, WRAPROWS(A2:J2, 2),
    names, TAKE(data, , 1),
    probs, TAKE(data, , -1),
    cumulative_probs, SCAN(0, probs, SUM),
    random_number, RAND(),
    XLOOKUP(random_number, cumulative_probs, names, "", 1)
)


Tried This one too, Getting #NAME? error

@SamySomy - You need Excel 365. The formula worked perfectly for me.

Here is my attempt assuming you have Excel 365:
=LET(
    array,A2:J2,
    elements,COUNTA(array)/2,
    names,CHOOSECOLS(array,SEQUENCE(1,elements,1,2)),
    cumulative,SCAN(0, CHOOSECOLS(array,SEQUENCE(1,elements,2,2)), LAMBDA(a,b, a + b)),
    position,XMATCH(RAND(),cumulative,1),
    name,INDEX(names,,position),
    name)

This can no doubt be simplified and written in a much simpler way and I can't wait to see what others will do with it.

Solution 2, for earlier versions of Excel.  I cannot figure out how to do it without a helper column with the cumulative probabilities:
=INDEX(A2:J2,,(SUMPRODUCT(NOT((RAND()<=L2:L7))*1))*2-1)


